# The post method in jQuery sends undefined data in the request body

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, mongodb, crud

Hello everyone and in advance I wish you all the best for the new year.

I'm trying to run an API on localhost that will save data from inputs to MongoDB.

The problem occurs when sending data using the post method. undefined data is sent to the request point (see screen)

[image]

At the same time, I can see in the console that the data in the request variable is and is also in JSON format (see screen)

[image]

But no data is saved to my mongoDB (see screen)

[image]

My html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="items">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Qunatity</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="addItem">
        <h2>Add new procuts</h2>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
        <label for="price">Price</label>
        <input type="text" name="price" id="price">
        <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
        <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity">
        <button>Add product</button>
    </div>
    <script src="./scripts/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My script.js

```
$(() => {
    let table = $('table');

    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "http://localhost:3000/api/products",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            let data = response;
            $(data).each(function (i, product) { 
                 $(table).append(`<tr><td>1</td><td>${product.name}</td><td>${product.price}</td><td>${product.quantity}</td></tr>`)
            });
        }
    });


    $('button').on('click', function(e){

        let request = JSON.stringify({
            name: $('#name').val(),
            price: $('#price').val(),
            itemQuantity: $('#quantity').val()
        });

        console.log(request);
        
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:3000/api/products",
            type: "json",
            data: request,
            contentType: "application/json"
        })
    })
})
```

My api

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/shop', { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB!'))
    .catch(err => console.error('Could not connect to MongoDB... ', err));

app.listen(3000, ()=> console.log('Listening on port 3000'));

app.use(cors());

const itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    price: Number,
    quantity: Number,
})

const Item = mongoose.model('Products', itemSchema);

app.get('/api/products', (req, res) => {
    Item.find().then(products => {res.json(products)})
});

app.post('/api/products', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    Item.create(req.body)
      .then(result => { res.json(result) })
      .catch(err => { res.send(" Error") });
});
```

Does anyone know why my data is not being saved to the database?

Searched for an answer here and tried all the threads, but all to no avail.

I also tried writing the code

```
$.post(URL,data,callback);
```

I also searched the book jQuery Cookbook for an answer

All to no avail. They always send me request.body undefined data

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `type: "json",` - `type` is an alias for `method`. That should be `dataType: "json"` (if you expect JSON as response)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but the problem still persists

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

If someone had the same problem, it was enough to add to api.js to solve it

```
app.use(express.json());
```